# Create Option 'Sub Menu' to Navigation

Tags: jquery, navigation

I'm using the following code to convert standard navigation into a Select Menu for responsive theme in Wordpress.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("<select />").appendTo("nav");

    $("<option />", {
        "selected": "selected",
        "value": "",
        "text": "Go to..."
    }).appendTo("nav select");

    $("nav a").each(function () {
        var el = $(this);
        $("<option />", {
            "value": el.attr("href"),
            "text": el.text()
        }).appendTo("nav select");
    });

    $("nav select").change(function () {
        window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
    });

    $('#navigasi_menu_reseponsive').remove();
});
```

Everything work fine with above code. I am wondering how to add a condition for working with submenus though. For example, here is the default html that a WordPress navigation creates.

```
<nav>
    <div id="navigasi_menu_reseponsive">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-500">
            <a href="http://localhost/themes123/category/portfolio/">Custom Color</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-349">
            <a href="#">Category</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-246">
                    <a href="http://localhost/themes123/category/interior/">Interior</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-548">
                    <a href="http://localhost/themes123/category/portfolio/">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-245">
                    <a href="http://localhost/themes123/category/lifestyle/">Lifestyle</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-367">
                    <a href="http://localhost/themes123/category/examples/">Examples</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I would like to do is prepend '-' to each ul that has a class of sub-menu so that my list looks like this:

Go to...

Category (this would be the parent)

-- Interior ( this would be the child with '-' )

-- Portfolio ( this would be the child with '-' )

-- Lifestyle

-- Examples

etc...

Can someone help out? Thanks

Comment: This is my current code (Select Menu) in JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/SzBcm/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/SzBcm/3/ check shorter code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/SzBcm/2/

```
$('ul.sub-menu li a').each(function(index, item) {
    $(this).text('--' + $(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/S3BJU/1/)

```
$('.sub-menu li').prepend('--');
```

update

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/SzBcm/3/)

```
$('.sub-menu li a').prepend('--')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $select = $("<select />").appendTo("nav");

    $("<option />", {
        "selected": "selected",
        "value": "",
        "text": "Go to..."
    }).appendTo($select);

    function add($ct, $a){
        $("<option />", {
            "value": $a.attr("href"),
            "text": $a.text()
        }).appendTo($ct);

    }

    function addGroup($group, $ul){
        $ul.children().each(function(){
            var $li = $(this), $a = $li.children('a');
            add($group, $a)
        })
    }

    $('#navigasi_menu_reseponsive > li').each(function(){
        var $li = $(this), $a = $li.children('a');

        if($li.is(':has(ul)')){
            var $group = $('<optgroup />', {
                label: $a.text()
            }).appendTo($select);
            addGroup($group, $li.children('ul'));
        } else {
            add($select, $a)
        }
    })

    $("nav select").change(function () {
        window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
    });

    $('#navigasi_menu_reseponsive').remove();

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Xran4/)